# x.jpg appears as a box in Xcode editor

Tags: ios, xcode

Forgive me for my silly question! I'm new to iOS here's my stupid issue - 
When I try setting an image as,

```
img.image = image.jpg
```

[image: screenshot]
the image.jpg appears as a box in the xcode editor. Why is that so? Is it good practice to do so?

I'm using xcode 8.2.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIImage(named:)` in general.

```
image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bow_s") // See the image below
image = UIImage(named: "bow_s")! // same with first
```

[image: sample 1]

[image: sample 2]